# Java, stop executing command

Tags: java, command-line, actionlistener

I'm making command line program, that is used by writing simple commands via `Scanner`.

One of those commands does something like that

```
  while(isRunning) {
        for(SSHManager.Log log : SSHManager.getLogData()) {
            try {
                while(log.getInputStream().available() > 0) {
                    int readByte = log.getInputStream().read();
                    System.out.print(log.getFontColor().toString() + (char)readByte);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

It connects to few log files via SSH, tails all of them and prints output into console. Works like a charm. But, I'd like to have an option (like clicking single key or key combination) to abort this process, but not whole application (ctrl + c does it). All I need is a listener that will set `isRunning = false` after I press for example 'q' while program keeps printing something to output.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: If you're using Swing, [the key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) would be the place to start.  However, if you just exit the `while` loop, the `Process` will still be running.  If you're using a `Process`, then you may need to call [`destroy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy--) to stop it